# When hitting SOAP Request using zeep module then getting execption "The given SOAPAction None does not match an operation."

Tags: python, soap, zeep

I am executing SOAP webservice using WS-Security #PAsswordDigest using Zeep module in python. But when hitting request then getting like "The given SOAPAction None does not match an operation."

```py
    from zeep.wsse.username import UsernameToken
    from zeep import Client , Settings , xsd


    username = 'username'
    password = 'password'

    WSDL_URL = 'http://0.0.0.0:0000/wsdl/sdpService.wsdl'


    settings = Settings(strict=False, xml_huge_tree=True)
    token = UsernameToken(username, password, use_digest=True)

    client = Client(wsdl=WSDL_URL, wsse=token, service_name="UserService", port_name="UserServiceSOAP", settings=settings)

    header_value = {
        "SOAPAction" : ""
    }

    with client.settings(raw_response=True):
        response = client.service.Authenticate()

    print(response.text)
```

Hitting above request getting error

```xml
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body><soap:Fault><faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode><faultstring>The given SOAPAction None does not match an operation.</faultstring></soap:Fault></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: You are not using "header_value" anywhere, can you remove it and try?

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution using python >> zeep >> Plugin >> egress.

```
def egress(self, envelope, http_headers, operation, binding_options):
        self.log.info("Request XML to SERVER :: \n"+parseString(etree.tostring(envelope)).toprettyxml()+"\n")
        http_headers = {
            'Content-Type': 'text/xml; charset=utf-8',
            'SOAPAction': b'""'
        }
        return envelope, http_headers
```

I am able to modify the "SOAPAction" key value from "None" to ""

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in Zeep.

I've just run into the same problem and created a PR with a [fix](https://github.com/mvantellingen/python-zeep/pull/1283)